# Drupal 7 CCK List of world languages

Tags: drupal, cck

I need to create a signup form for translators from any country and give them option to submit the language combinations they can translate to and from. For this purpose I need a list of world languages in dropdown or multi-select widget format. I could not find any module that could make a CCK field of world languages.

Hope anyone can come up with any suggestion.

Comment: If you're using a webform to sign up with, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679756/how-to-create-array-of-all-the-language-in-drupal-form-dropdown-list

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use a taxonomy term reference field type with a taxonomy keyed to the languages table (see [language_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/language_list/6)), which you'd need to do either with a one time mapping (possibly using [taxonomy_xml](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_xml/)) or a custom module (although it sounds like you have more of a one time use case.)

This is not to be taken as a canonical solution, perhaps someone else has experience with a different approach.

Comment: Hi Forest, Thanks for your answer. I have created a taxonomy vocabulary Languages and have entered all the languages as terms.