# How to create array of all the language in drupal form dropdown list

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7, lang

I need to create dropdown list for all languages in my Drupal form, Is there any function in PHP to achieve this. I want to create an array of all languages and pass it to drupal form.

```
function video_upload_subtitles_form($form, &$form_state) {
 $form = array('#attributes' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
 $lang_list = array();//**how to create this array**
 $form['video_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Name Of the video'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
 );

 $form['sub_file'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#title' => t('Upload video'),
        '#description' => t('Pick a video file to upload.'),
    );
$form['user_list']=array(
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#title' => t('Language'),
    '#options' => $lang_list,//array of language
    '#multiple' => false,
    '#attributes'=>array('size'=>4),
    '#weight'=>8,
);
 $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
 );

 return $form;

}
```

I know listing of language can be done in php by listing and making a array manually but is it possible to do with any php function, just looking for some easy way to save time.

Got this cool website for [Country List](http://www.countries-list.info/) . Is there anything for the Language like this

Comment: try a changes and i hope this is usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    $select = db_select('Your table name', 's');
    $select = $select->fields('s',array('languages_name','id'));
    // 'languages_name' , 'id' this is a column
    $queried_nodes = $select->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc('id');
    $lang_list = array();
    foreach ($queried_nodes as $result)
    {   
       $lang_list[$result->languages_name] = t($result->languages_name);
    }
```

after set a $lang_list variable

```
$form['user_list']=array(
     '#type'=>'select',
     '#title' => t('Language'),
     '#options' => $lang_list,//array of language
     '#multiple' => false,
     '#attributes'=>array('size'=>4),
     '#weight'=>8,
);
```

you are create a new Language table or content types and you use a drupal inbuilt language list so try this code.

```
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/iso.inc';
  $lang = _locale_get_predefined_list();

  $lang_list = array();

  foreach ($lang as $key => $value) 
  {
    $lang_list[$value[0]] = t($value[0]);
  }
```

after use a `$lang_list` varible in form api

Comment: I need to know from where to get language list

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to put all the languages you want in a table in your DB.

Then you could just use the following code to create your select box:

```
$languages = db_query("SELECT id, name FROM languages")->fetchAllKeyed();

$form['language'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Choose language'),
    '#options' => $languages,
);
```

To populate your table of languages you can download a [csv here](http://code.google.com/p/routinelists/downloads/detail?name=languages.csv).

Comment: could you correct your csv and upload again it seems to be little incorrect